# Unity scene has phantom models in every scene new and existing a like even when deleted

Tags: unity

I have asked about this over at Unity Forums but have not got a response yet.
My issues is that in the image below all there is is a light source but several of my monster models are in the scene somehow. I cannot select them or interact with them in any fashion. The are there whether it is an existing scene or I create a new scene.
If anyone has any clue what this is from it would be a great help because it is driving me madd!
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That's really odd. I've never seen this before.

Comment: This looks like a bug to report to the Unity development team. Are you able to reproduce the problem in a new empty project? What steps do you need to go through to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact a bug. You have to restart Unity a couple of times but then they disappear. Not sure what the editor is holding onto to make this happen. But after 3 restarts of Unity everything is normal again.